# Pascal: Will not read anything from my file and getting errors

Tags: pascal

I've been stressing out for the past few hours trying to get this working and I simply cannot figure it out. Basically it doesn't read anything from my .dat file and when I try to use options 2, 3 or 4 it just comes up with these

[image: errors].

I've include the .dat file and pascal below. I'm desperate for help.

mytestfile.dat

```
1
Adele
Pop
2
Hello
ff
Remedy
dd
```

pascal

```
program MusicPlayer;
uses TerminalUserInput;

type
    TrackRec = record
        name: String;
        location: String;
    end;
    // type TrackArray = array of TrackRec;
    GenreType = (Pop, Rap, Rock, Classic);
    AlbumRec = Record
        name: String;
        genre: GenreType;
        // location: array of TrackRec; 
        tracks: array of TrackRec;
    end;
type AlbumArray = array of AlbumRec; 


function ReadGenre(): GenreType;
var
    option: Integer;
begin
    WriteLn('Press 1 for Pop');
    WriteLn('Press 2 for Rap');
    WriteLn('Press 3 for Rock');
    WriteLn('Press 4 for Classic');
    option := ReadInteger('');

    while (option<1) or (option>5) do
    begin
        WriteLn('Please enter a number between 1-4');
        option := ReadInteger('');
    end;

    case option of
        1: result := Pop;
        2: result := Rap;
        3: result := Rock;
    else
        result := Classic;
    end;
end;

procedure NewAlbum(var albums: AlbumArray; var myFile: TextFile);
var
    number, i, tracks, y: Integer;
begin
    AssignFile(myFile, 'mytestfile.dat');
    ReWrite(myFile);

    number := ReadInteger('How many albums do you want to make?: ');
    WriteLn(myFile, number);
    SetLength(albums, number);

    for i := Low(albums) to High(albums) do
    begin
        albums[i].name := ReadString('Enter album name:');
        WriteLn(myFile, albums[i].name);

        albums[i].genre := ReadGenre();
        WriteLn(myFile, albums[i].genre);

        tracks := ReadIntegerRange('How many tracks do you want to enter? (max 15)', 0, 15);
        WriteLn(myFile, tracks);
        SetLength(albums[i].tracks, tracks);

        for y := Low(albums[i].tracks) to tracks - 1 do 
        begin
            albums[i].tracks[i].name := ReadString('Track name:');
            WriteLn(myFile, albums[i].tracks[i].name);
            albums[i].tracks[i].location := ReadString('Track Location:');
            WriteLn(myFile, albums[i].tracks[i].location);
        end;
    end;
    Close(myFile);
end;

procedure ReadTrack(count: Integer; var albums: AlbumArray; var myFile: TextFile);
var
    i: Integer;
begin
    ReadLn(myFile, i);
    SetLength(albums[count].tracks, i);
    for count := Low(albums[count].tracks) to High(albums[count].tracks) - 1 do
    begin
        ReadLn(myFile, albums[count].tracks[i].name);
        ReadLn(myFile, albums[count].tracks[i].location);
    end;
end;

procedure ReadAlbum(var albums: AlbumArray; var myFile: TextFile);
var
    albumNumber, tracknumber, count, i: Integer;

begin
    AssignFile(myFile, 'mytestfile.dat');
    Reset(myFile);
    ReadLn(myFile, albumNumber);
    SetLength(albums, albumNumber); 

    for i := Low(albums) to High(albums) do
    begin
        ReadLn(myFile, albums[i].name);
        ReadLn(myFile, albums[i].genre);
        ReadLn(myFile, tracknumber);
        SetLength(albums[i].tracks, tracknumber);
        for count := Low(albums[count].tracks) to tracknumber - 1 do
        begin
            ReadLn(myFile, albums[count].tracks[i].name);
            ReadLn(myFile, albums[count].tracks[i].location);
        end;
    end;
end;

procedure ReadAlbums(var albums: AlbumArray; var myFile: TextFile);
var 
    i, number: Integer;
begin
    ReadAlbum(albums, myFile);
    WriteLn('Album is:');
    for i := Low(albums) to High(albums) do
    begin
        WriteLn((i + 1),'.', albums[i].name);
        WriteLn('.', albums[i].genre);
        for number := Low(albums[i].tracks) to High(albums[i].tracks) do
        begin
            WriteLn((number + 1), '', albums[i].tracks[Low(albums[i].tracks)].name);
        end;
    end;
end;

procedure PlayAlbum (var albums: AlbumArray; var myFile: TextFile);
var
    i, number: Integer;
begin

    ReadAlbums(albums, myFile);

    i := ReadInteger('Please select an album: ');
    i := i - 1;
    number := ReadIntegerRange('Please select a song from album:', 1, 20);
    number := number - 1;

    WriteLn('Now playing');
    WriteLn('Track selected: ', albums[i].tracks[number].name);
    WriteLn('Album: ', albums[i].name);

end;

procedure Update(var albums: AlbumArray; var myFile: TextFile);
var
    i: Integer;
begin
    ReadAlbums(albums, myFile);
    i := ReadInteger('Select an album to update');
    i := i - 1;
    albums[i].name := ReadString('New Album Name:');
    WriteLn('Album has now been updated');
end;

procedure Main();
var
    i, count, select, change: Integer;
    albums: AlbumArray;
    myFile: TextFile;
begin

    WriteLn('Please select an option: ');
    WriteLn('-------------------------');
    WriteLn('1. Read Albums');
    WriteLn('2. Display Albums');
    WriteLn('3. Select an Album');
    WriteLn('4. Update an Album');
    WriteLn('5. Exit');
    WriteLn('-------------------------');
    repeat
        i := ReadInteger('Select option for menu:');
        case i of  
            1: ReadAlbum(albums, myFile);

            2: ReadAlbums(albums, myFile);

            3: PlayAlbum(albums, myFile);

            4: Update(albums, myFile);
        end;
    until i = 5;
end;

begin
    Main();
end.
```

Comment: The menu you show to the user and the function/procedure you call based on their input doesn't really match: `Menu: 1 Read Albums`, `case i of 1: NewAlbum`, etc. Don't know if this causes the problem you ask about.

Comment: @TomBrunBerg Yes sorry that was my fault, I was tinkering around with it, the newAlbum is suppose to be ReadAlbum. I'm going to change that now but the problem still persists with the readalbum not working

Comment: On which **exact** line of your code does the AV occur?  Which Pascal compiler are you using?

Comment: @MartynA Sorry, i think I missed adding the tag. I'm using free pascal. Not sure what you mean by the abbreviated AV but i believe the issue lies in the ReadAlbum as it is what is used on the first line on most of the other procedures/functions

Comment: AV = Access Violation.  " i believe the issue lies in the ReadAlbum"  I think you are missing my point.  We readers cannot see your screen so cannot know (unless you tell us) which line of your code is executing when the AV occurs - that's why I asked.  ReadAlbum isn't an answer to that, because it is several lines long, and an AV occurs on a *particular* line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `ReadAlbum()` procedure you have two `for` loops, an outer one that loops through the albums and an inner one that loops through the tracks. In the latter you have messed up the indexes:

This is the erroneous code:

```
    for count := Low(albums[count].tracks) to tracknumber - 1 do
    begin
        ReadLn(myFile, albums[count].tracks[i].name);
        ReadLn(myFile, albums[count].tracks[i].location);
    end;
```

`albums[]` should use `i` as index and `tracks[]` should use `count` as index.

Until you get more used to arrays and indexes I suggest you name your variables with a clear meaning, for example:

```
`NumOfAlbums` in the meaning of how many albums you have
`AlbumIndex` as the index to the albums array
`NumOfTracks` as the number of tracks in an album
`TrackIndex` as the index to the tracks array
```

It may feel tiresome to write so long names, but you would probably not have made the mistake you did, with the more verbose names.